# How to calculate IoU metric if there is no mask

Tags: computer-vision, metric

For example: YOLOv8 segmentation doesn't output any mask for concrete class if no masks was detected, but there is a mask for this class in the ground truth masks.

I should set metric to zero for such pairs?